# Bold selective text from string based on start/end position

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, arrays, string

In my ASP.NET page, I have a string (returned from SQL db). I would like to bold certain part of the string text based on given text position.

For example, if I have a string as follows:

```
"This is an example to show where to bold the text"
```

And I am given character start position: 6 and end position: 7, then I would bold the word "is" in my string, getting:

"This **is** an example to show where to bold the text"

Any ideas?

EDIT: Keep in mind I need to use the start/end position as there may be duplicate words in the string.

Comment: Did you tried _anything_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Insert a close tag into position 7 of the string
2. Insert an open tag into position 5 (6 - 1) of the string.
3. You will get a string like "This **is** an example…"

I.e. modify string (insert markup) from end to start:

```
var result = str.Insert(7, "</b>").Insert(6 - 1, "<b>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) method for this.

> Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in
>   the current instance are replaced with another specified string.

```
string s = "This is an example to show where to bold the text".Replace(" is ", " <b>is</b> ");
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/zXfQEe).

Since you clear what you want, you can use `StringBuilder` class.

```
string s = "This is an example to show where to bold the text";
var sb = new StringBuilder(s);
sb.Remove(5, 2);
sb.Insert(5, "<b>is</b>");
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/U6awnz).

***NOTE***: Since you didn't see `<b>` tags as an output, it doesn't mean they are not there `;)`

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention, but I only want to bold the text within the position. E.g. if the world "is" occurs multiple times in the text, I only want to bold the text within the specified position.

Comment: @highwingers Based on OP's example, it works. You are right but the question is anot perfectly clear at all..

Comment: Let me edit the question - I did specify the start and end position in my original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First find the string to replace in your full string.
Replace the string with `<b>+replacestring+</b>`

```
string str="This is an example to show where to bold the text";
string replaceString="string to replace"
str=str.Replace(replaceString,<b>+replaceString+</b>);
```

### Edit 1

```
string replaceString=str.Substring(6,2);
str=str.Replace(replaceString,<b>+replaceString+</b>);
```

SubString Example:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring

### Edit 2

```
int startPosition=6;
int lastPosition=7;
int lastIndex=lastPosition-startPosition+1;

string str="This is an example to show where to bold the text";
string replaceString=str.Substring(startPosition,lastIndex);
str=str.Replace(replaceString,<b>+replaceString+</b>);
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention there might be duplicates, but I only want to bold the word within the position specified.

Comment: Thank you very much Shekhar! I appreciate it. But I do not want to bold multiple occurrences of the word "is" (if it appears multiple times). Only the one occurrences based on the start/end position? Is that do-able?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this...

**

```
strStart = MID(str, 0 , 7) ' Where 7 is the START position
str2Replace = "<b>" & MID(str, 8, 10) & "</b>" ' GRAB the part of string you want to replace
str_remain = MId(str, 11, Len(str)) ' Remaining string
Response.write(strStart  & str2Replace & str_remain )
```

**

Comment: Thanks highwingers...one question - how do I get the MID function in my ASP.NET c# application?

Comment: Oh, I think it's called substring

Comment: yup, its called substring, however be carefull...substring/mid index starts with "0", so you might need to play around with parameters.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx

Comment: thanks - I ended up using something called Insert instead as it was cleaner. appreciate your help though!